# Информация в консоли

Tags: c++, консоль

Как программно "достать" информацию из консоли?

Например, поместить в строку `string`.

Comment: Достать это что?

Comment: @nikita Вопрос не ясен.

Comment: Я же написал "Например, поместить в строку string
". Т.е. в консоль с помощью, например, cout была выведена какая-то информация, а работа программы продолжается. Как программе прочитать то, что в консоли

Comment: Думаю, что только через файл. Направить выполнение в файл, и, затем раскрывать его из программы. Правда. тогда зачем нужна консоль?

Comment: @nikita Пожалуйста, конретизируйте вопрос. Поясните что вы понимаете под "достать"? Под "консолью" вы понимаете стандартный поток ввода\вывода, если да то какой\какие именно?

Comment: похоже на [XY-вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Если под Windows, то для этого есть функция [ReadConsoleOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684965%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Для кроссплатформенного решения, вероятно, нужно использовать что-то типа [ncurses](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: Как использовать второе, можно конкретнее?

Comment: @nikita первое, что гуглится - это функции [inch](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inch).